# Extract both occurrences of pattern Regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have an input vector as follows:

```
input <- c("fdsfs iwantthis (1,1,1,1) fdsaaa   iwantthisaswell (2,3,4,5)", "fdsfs thistoo (1,1,1,1)")
```

And I would like to use a regex to extract the following:

```
> output
[1] "iwantthis iwantthisaswell" "thistoo"
```

I have managed to extract every word that is before an opening bracket.
I tried this to get only the first word:

```
> gsub(".*?[[:space:]](.*?)[[:space:]]\\(.*", "\\1", input)
[1] "iwantthis" "thistoo"
```

But I cannot get it to work for multiple occurrences:

```
    > gsub(".*?[[:space:]](.*?)[[:space:]]\\(.*?[[:space:]](.*?)[[:space:]]\\(.*", "\\1 \\2", input)
[1] "iwantthis iwantthisaswell" "fdsfs thistoo (1,1,1,1)"
```

The closest I have managed is the following:

```
library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(input, "(\\S*)\\s\\(")
[[1]]
[1] "iwantthis ("       "iwantthisaswell ("

[[2]]
[1] "thistoo ("
```

I am sure I am missing something in my regex (not that good at it) but what?

Comment: are there any cases in your real data that are not correctly output in R by `gsub('\\w.+? ([^\\s]+) \\(.+?\\)','\\1', input, perl=TRUE)` ? If so please let me know and I'll be happy to attempt to refine the single line gsub solution to match any exceptions not in your original example.

Comment: No my data is pretty clean, the only cases I have are the ones mentioned here. Thank you for the offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
> sapply(str_extract_all(input, "\\S+(?=\\s*\\()"), paste, collapse=" ")
[1] "iwantthis iwantthisaswell" "thistoo"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b3sIwo/1). The `\\S+(?=\\s*\\()` will extract all 1+ non-whitespace chunks from a text before a `(` char preceded with 0+ whitespaces. `sapply` with `paste` will join the found matches with a space (with `collapse=" "`).

**Pattern details**

- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?=\s*\()` - a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) that requires the presence of 0+ whitespace chars (`\s*`) and then a `(` char (`\(`) immediately to the right of the current position.

Comment: That works like a charm! May I ask how you would approach this in the gsub scenario with capturing groups?

Comment: @User2321 Please clarify what you are after: a pure single regex solution with `gsub`, or do you "allow" a bit of common programming logic around the regex function? Do you want to only use base R?

Comment: The solution you gave is perfect. I wanted to see how you would approach the issue with a pure regex for gsub (mainly curiosity)

Comment: Ok, I will see, because something like `library(qdapRegex)` -> `rm_white(gsub("(?:(\\S+)\\s*\\()?.", "\\1 ", input))` is working, too. And `gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$|(\\s)+", "\\1", gsub("(?:(\\S+)\\s*\\()?.", "\\1 ", input))` should also do the job

Comment: @User2321 A single regex approach with `gsub` won't work here because you need to replace with a space, and the spaces will inevitably appear either at the start or end of the string, so you will have to use `trimws` at least.

Comment: I've added a solution that shows how to use just `gsub`

Comment: @User2321 Please remove the upvote from krads answer, it is wrong (now you may do it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
unlist(regmatches(input, gregexpr("\\w+(?= \\()", input, perl = TRUE)))
#[1] "iwantthis"       "iwantthisaswell" "thistoo"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in R:

```
gsub('\\w.+? ([^\\s]+) \\(.+?\\)','\\1', input, perl=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
[1] "iwantthis iwantthisaswell" "thistoo"
```

UPDATED to work for the general case.  E.g. now finds "i_wantthisaswell2" by searching on non-spaces between the other matches.

Using other suggested general case inputs:

```
general_cases <- c("fdsfs iwantthis (1,1,1,1) fdsaaa   iwantthisaswell (2,3,4,5)", 
                   "fdsfs thistoo (1,1,1,1) ",
                   "GaGa iwant_this (1,1,1,1)", 
                   "lal2!@#$%^&*()_+a i_wantthisaswell2 (2,3,4,5)")
gsub('\\w.+? ([^\\s]+) \\(.+?\\)','\\1', general_cases, perl=TRUE)
```

results:

```
[1] "iwantthis iwantthisaswell" "thistoo "                 
[3] "iwant_this"                "i_wantthisaswell2"
```

Comment: [It does not work](https://regex101.com/r/dRHaG8/1) in general case. It won't work with a lot of strings, e.g. `iwant_this (1,1,1,1)` and `i_wantthisaswell2 (2,3,4,5)`, etc. It won't work [if there is some free text  at the end](https://regex101.com/r/dRHaG8/3) (it won't remove it). I did not post my `gsub` solutions and kept them in the comments for a reason. There cannot be a pure one call to `gsub` solution for this. Though you might do something with a `gsubfn`, but it will look very cumbersome.

Comment: @Wiktor It looks like the regex test you linked used an option for pcre specific to PHP.  But the OP posted this question with the [r] tag and with R code samples.  My solution works if run in R session (I'm running 3.4.4). Also the above solution works when you use an R specific regex online tester:  http://rextester.com/SGLF35198

Comment: The PCRE option at the regex101.com is exactly showing you the behavior of `gsub` used with the `perl=TRUE` argument. PHP uses PCRE and `gsub` uses PCRE when the `perl=TRUE` is passed to it. Your "solution" only "works fine" for a single sentence OP posted, but it won't work in *a general case*.

Comment: Updated to show gsub can work for the general case of capturing all non-space characters, including underscores and numbers.  E.g. can capture "i_wantthisaswell2"

Comment: [No, `\\w.+? ([^\\s]+) \\(.+?\\)` does not work.](https://regex101.com/r/dRHaG8/4)  Your answer is still very wrong.

Comment: [Your `'\\w.+? ([^\\s]+) \\(.+?\\)'` update still fails with many inputs](https://ideone.com/TDIkIC). **There is no way to achieve what OP wants with a single call to `gsub`**.

Comment: @Wiktor.  With all due respect, there are subtle differences with pcre implementation between R and php. **The output I've pasted is direct from an R session (R 3.4.4) which everyone is welcome to test and confirm in an R session.** Alternatively, it would be valid to test using R specific online regex tester such as one demonstrating my solution works with R:  http://rextester.com/JYVH40639  If you like it may be a great SO question to ask about the differences between PHP an R implementations of PCRE.